# Xunit Green/Red dot is not visible even test cases are passed

Tags: .net, xunit

I am getting the issue the green/red dot is not visible even the test case passed/failed. Actually I have downgraded my Visual Studio to 17.5.4. So I think it is happening because of that. Before, I was able to see that green/red dot. In the picture below you can see there my both test cases are working fine but I am not able to see the green/red dot.

[image]

I have searched on internet but wasn't able to find any solution till now.

Comment: Can you add NetworkUtilityTest file screenshot?